# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a class called Person and a List called People, show below:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<Person> People;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            People = new List<Person>();
            People.Add(new Person() { ID = 1, Name = "John" });
            People.Add(new Person() { ID = 2, Name = "Mike" });
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I want to display the 2 Person in People to an DataGrid, using a combobox to choose between the 2 Person.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Height="300">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Name}">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=People}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=People}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

But the DataGrid just display nothing at all. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt it be inside a  `<DataGrid.Columns>` tag?

Comment: It does provide a partial answer, in that the author's code won't work until the column definition is wrapped in `<DataGrid.Columns>`, but there are other issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. `People` must be a property, not a field.
2. You must populate the collection *before* assigning it to `People`, **or** you must replace the list with an `ObservableCollection<Person>` so the grid will detect the items you've added.
3. You must assign `People` *before* the call to `InitializeComponent()`, **or** the class containing the property must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire the `PropertyChanged` when `People` is assigned so the grid detects the new collection.
4. As @Koen points out, your column definitions must be collectively surrounded by a `<DataGrid.Columns>` tag.